# remove whitespace/garbage from html encoded scring

Tags: php, html, regex

I made a regex to remove whitespaces and other garbage such as new lines and tabs.

```
preg_replace('/[\s\t\n\r]+/mu', ' ', $var);
```

However my string is html encoded, which means I get some chars replaced with &#...;

What could we do to account for the encoded chars as well?

Comment: Can you give us an example input string and what your desired output would be?

Comment: Imagine string full of tabs, spaces, new lines, and you'll get it. Now imagine some of them are html encoded, eg &nbsp; etc.

Comment: I was thinking more of a real example. Not a description of an example. _Show_ us a value of `$var`. You need to be specific about exactly which parts of the string you want to replce, not just _"whitespaces and other garbage"_. The problem is you're question is too general to the point that if someone gives you an answer that might help, they'll likely be missing something you need to remove because you weren't specific enough.

Comment: I'm looking for the equivalent for the above regex, which is 100% valid, and removes the following characters: \s \t \n \r, and I want to expand it to match their encoded equivalents as well.

Comment: Again, you really need to give an example of `$var`. Not doing so is making it difficult for you to get a good and thorough answer. I'm not sure why that is difficult. Good luck.

Comment: `\s` already contains `\t\r\n` so specifying them is redundant.

Comment: Didn't know that... then the problem now is about combining \s with  &#09; and let's say &nbsp; at least. If we make or statement in the regex, may result in white space if we have some sequence of encoded tabs and spaces. Eg: /\s+|&#09;/ this may result in multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it's possible to make quantifiers like that to the groups.

```
preg_replace('/(\s|&#09;|&nbsp;)+/mu', ' ', $var)
```

**Edit**

Yes, this appears to be working:

```
$str='&nbsp; t &#09; &nbsp;&nbsp;  e &#09;  &#09;  &#09;  s&#09;t&#09;  ';

echo '|'.preg_replace('/(\s|&#09;|&nbsp;)+/mu',' ',$str).'|';
```

^ produces the expected result: `| t e s t |`

Answer (score 0):

you could first do an html decode, then apply the regex, end then encode it again

something like this:

```
$result = htmlentities(preg_replace('/[\s\t\n\r]+/mu', ' ', html_entity_decode($var)));
```

Answer (score 0):

A single regular expression may not be enough.

This will replace any entity-encoded **ascii** value that is not a control character with it's actual ascii character, control-characters by space, and leave everything above 126 alone.

```
<?php
$in = "&amp;&#032;&#192;&#12;";

$out = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d{1,4});/u', function($match) {
        $v = $match[1]+0;
        if($v < 33) return ' ';
        elseif($v > 126) return $match[0];
        else return chr($v);
}, $in);
$out = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/mu', ' ', $out);

echo $out;
?>
```

**Note:** technically 127 (`ESC`) is ascii too, but I skipped it for the sake of a shorter example.

You could either expand the callback (and the regex) or remove named entities in an intermediate step. However note that `&nbsp;` is not equivalent to `&#32;` but rather `&#160;` which is a space-width invisible character that may not wrap. Same goes for other named entities (you usually want to keep `&shy;`, `&amp;`, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Use `html_entity_decode()` first and then `preg_replace`, e.g.

```
preg_replace('/[\s\t\n\r]+/mu', ' ', html_entity_decode($var));
```

Comment: well, this is insufficient, and may also potentially result in the loss of data